# Stop Latex \SI from automatically formatting 35 to 3.5 x 10^1

Tags: latex

I have encountered a strange problem with the si unit package.

I type `\SI{35}{\MeV}` and the output **I get is 3.5 x10^1 MeV, but I want 35 MeV.**

I can't seem to find the right parameter, below are the packages I use so far in the latex-beamer-document:

```
 \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
 \usetheme{Bruno}
 \usepackage{subfig} 
 \usepackage[italic]{hepnames}
 \usepackage[ugly]{units}
 \usepackage[scientific-notation=true]{siunitx}
```

Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: Please make a [mre] instead of this code fragment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the scientific notation, don't force `siunits` to use it:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[
%scientific-notation=true
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\SI{35}{\MeV}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]